# My Laptop can't see GPT formatted flash drives

Tags: windows

(There are 2 questions, but you only need to solve one.)

So I installed Tiny11 Beta 2 on my computer. So it was pretty common stuff, but my problem lies with the BIOS. For whatever reason my laptop will not see any flash drives (mostly Windows installation ones, Linux ones work fine) but it will see drives (yes, I have a disk reader card thing)

So there are two things with the problem here. When I format my drive using Rufus using UEFI or using GPT (they're the same thing), my computer can't see them.
(I haven't actually tried formatting a Windows ISO with the default setting Rufus gives, or I did? I don't quite remember)

So I usually format them in MBR. The only problem is my computer seems to not like MBR. This one issue means that if I don't enable the OPROM Legacy mode, it will single-Handley not boot and just go to the system checkup screen.

So uh, am I doing something wrong when it comes to formatting drives?
Also, there are two things I can do here:

One, I can follow the suggestions and fixes you guys made and use them in the future when formatting Windows drives. (Which will definitely be better in the long run).

Two, I could just use a temporary Windows PE Environment and use a tool to re-convert the MBR disk to GPT. Why is this? Cause If you format Windows with MBR, it will only install on MBR disks.

So uh, yeah... I need help with that.
I have a DELL Inspiron 14-3473 Laptop If you're curious.

Comment: UEFI≠GPT. GUID=GPT. UEFI boot needs an EFI partition, on a GPT/GUID drive.

Comment: And your Dell Inspiron should be installed in UEFI mode..

Comment: "So I usually format them in MBR.' - This means Windows is installed in Legacy mode, which I am surprised even works, since Windows 11 does not support Legacy mode. My suggestion, use MBR2GPT if it wasn't removed out of Tiny 11, and convert to GPT.

Comment: You could post that as the answer. Answering your own questions is perfectly OK.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue has been resolved, per the author, and no answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I was actually pretty damn dumb. I formatted it with GPT FAT32 and it worked. I should've done some testing before posting this